# How can I make this more lightweight javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript.

Is there away to make this simpler. It seems very heavy?

It basically take the value of 12 inputs and changes an array based on these values

```
   function updatechart (){
    var inputnoinsulation1 = document.getElementById("noinsulation1").value
    var inputnoinsulation2 = document.getElementById("noinsulation2").value
    var inputnoinsulation3 = document.getElementById("noinsulation3").value
    var inputnoinsulation4 = document.getElementById("noinsulation4").value
    var inputnoinsulation5 = document.getElementById("noinsulation5").value
    var inputnoinsulation6 = document.getElementById("noinsulation6").value
    var inputnoinsulation7 = document.getElementById("noinsulation7").value
    var inputnoinsulation8 = document.getElementById("noinsulation8").value
    var inputnoinsulation9 = document.getElementById("noinsulation9").value
    var inputnoinsulation10 = document.getElementById("noinsulation10").value
    var inputnoinsulation11 = document.getElementById("noinsulation11").value
    var inputnoinsulation12 = document.getElementById("noinsulation12").value

    chart1data[0].NoInsulation = (parseInt(inputnoinsulation1));
    chart1data[1].NoInsulation = (parseInt(inputnoinsulation2));
    chart1data[2].NoInsulation = (parseInt(inputnoinsulation3));
    chart1data[3].NoInsulation = (parseInt(inputnoinsulation4));
    chart1data[4].NoInsulation = (parseInt(inputnoinsulation5));
    chart1data[5].NoInsulation = (parseInt(inputnoinsulation6));
    chart1data[6].NoInsulation = (parseInt(inputnoinsulation7));
    chart1data[7].NoInsulation = (parseInt(inputnoinsulation8));
    chart1data[8].NoInsulation = (parseInt(inputnoinsulation9));
    chart1data[9].NoInsulation = (parseInt(inputnoinsulation10));
    chart1data[10].NoInsulation = (parseInt(inputnoinsulation11));
    chart1data[11].NoInsulation = (parseInt(inputnoinsulation12));
```

Comment: Why did I get marked down for this?

Comment: This may be a basic loop question for most, but don't think the OP deserves a down vote for asking this as he may be trying to learn the optimal way to arrive at his solution .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++)
     chart1data[i].NoInsulation = parseInt(document.getElementById("noinsulation" + (i + 1)).value);
```

Should work.

Comment: `i < 12` otherwise correct. I was just going to write the same answer.

Comment: int i? JavaScript has no "int".

Comment: @zvona You are right, should be var. I was working with Java just moments ago :D

Comment: You should probably specify the radix for `parseInt`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 0, l = 12;

for (;i<l;++i) {
    var val = window.parseInt(document.getElementById("noinsulation"+ (i+1)).value, 10);
    chart1data[i].NoInsulation = val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var index = 0;
while (index < 12) chart1data[index++].NoInsulation =
    parseInt(document.getElementById("noinsulation" + index).value);
```

In addition it's always a good practice to specify the second parameter of `parseInt` (i.e. the radix). It won't make any difference in this case, but you should get in the habit of doing it:

```
var index = 0;
while (index < 12) chart1data[index++].NoInsulation =
    parseInt(document.getElementById("noinsulation" + index).value, 10);
```

Hope this helps.